# The legality of bombing an embassy

Tags: rules-of-war, embassy, serbia

During the bombing of Serbia, the Chinese embassy was bombed by US forces using five GPS-guided bombs. Although the US claimed that it was an accident, many believed that it was because the US aimed to destroy the fragments of the downed F-117 stealth attack aircraft stored in the basement.

Is it legal to attack the embassy of your opponent for this reason, despite not being at war with said opponent?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?   Of course it would be illegal to bomb the embassy on purpose, if that was actually the reason.  So what are you asking and why are you asking it?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Because China must be in the talks with Serbia for them to have the fragment of F-117, so China is not only talking to the enemy of US, but also having a piece of US property that US has to keep secret. Does this make the bombing valid?

Comment: I was about to WTC, but since this question has recieved a clear and helpful answer to the question you *may* have intended, I suggest you clarify the question.

Comment: If that was the reason, they surely done a poor job. The building was still standing after the strike. So getting stuff in the basement was likely not the reason. Compare with multiple similar buildings totally demolished by the Israeli air force during the 2006 Lebanon war (using US bombs). So flattening a building (like that) is not so hard, but that doesn't seem to have been the intent there.

Comment: Most of the Yugoslav-released photos show just the heavily trashed facade on one side, but there are some photos that show the extent of the damage to the whole building, which wasn't that much. http://wikimapia.org/62550/United-States-bombing-of-the-Chinese-embassy-in-Belgrade#/photo/188389 Unless the US knew exactly in which side of the building something might have been kept, this is a pretty implausible theory.

Comment: Photo from the other side of the building https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/C861/production/_106779215_shutterstock_editorial_8355819e_huge-2.jpg.webp

Comment: Can you add a citation for the many believed part of your question?

Comment: It is obviously a violation of the domestic law of the place where the bombing took place and the country whose embassy it is. The answers assume, probably rightly, that you really mean to ask about under the international treaty created laws of war when it is done as an act of war. But, the shallower answer is that, of course, it is against the laws of China and Serbia to bomb China's embassy in Serbia.

Comment: I thought "many believed" that it was because there was radar on the embassy that was used in air defence.

Answer (score 11):

**No.**

Protocol I to the Geneva Conventions, Article 52, provides for the general protection of civilian objects, hindering attacks to military objectives in a war between two or more belligerents. Article 52 states:

> Attacks shall be limited strictly to military objectives. In so far as objects are concerned, military objectives are limited to those objects which by their nature, location, purpose or use make an effective contribution to military action and whose total or partial destruction, capture or neutralization, in the circumstances ruling at the time, offers a definite military advantage.

Embassies of countries not participating in conflict are definitely not legitimate military targets, even if they are facilitating communication with a hostile country.

Acquiring secret military equipment from said hostile country is also not illegal. If you want to keep something secret, that's your problem, other countries are not obligated to avoid finding or transferring to others your secrets, unless they have a binding treaty with you (like, for example, [this EU-UK treaty](https://ec.europa.eu/info/strategy/relations-non-eu-countries/relations-united-kingdom/eu-uk-trade-and-cooperation-agreement/eu-uk-security-information-agreement_en)). Fragments of shot down aircraft are [war booty](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/customary-ihl/eng/docs/v2_rul_rule49) and, according to most countries (including USA) military manuals, belong to the state that captured them; that state is thus within their rights to sell or otherwise transfer their ownership to, for example, China.

Official position of the USA supports this view. According to [disclosed information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_bombing_of_the_Chinese_embassy_in_Belgrade), the strike was not intended for the embassy, and was a result of a mistake in target coordinates. USA denied the bombing was deliberate, formally apologized to the Chinese Government, offered compensation for the incident and [punished people responsible for the strike](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411035733/https://www.theguardian.com/world/2000/apr/10/balkans). Even if we assume all of it was just a cover-up for an actual deliberate strike - it is clear that whoever was responsible for it never doubted that if it ever came out there was no way to spin it as a legitimate operation.

Comment: @Fizz yes, [a Danish newspaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_bombing_of_the_Chinese_embassy_in_Belgrade#The_Observer/Politiken_report) claimed that an anonymous source from British MoD told them the Chinese allowed the embassy to be used as a communication base by Serb forces. AFAIK, no evidence turned up to back up this story, and both UK and US officials vehemently denied the story had any truth to it.

Comment: "punished people responsible for the strike" can you provide a reference for this?
Even when american pilots killed 20 people for fun ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_Cavalese_cable_car_crash ) the airmen were quickly brought to the US and then 15 years later discharged from service because they deleted the tape from that flight, while they received no punishment for the disaster itself (yes, by itself the US paid 65'000 usd per victim, less than Boeing is paying for the 737 MAX victims, before being forced to pay more due to some NATO treaties enforced by the italian government)

Comment: @EarlGrey added a link to a news article. Note that the punishment in question was basically a slap on the wrist in this case, too, and followed about 11 months of constant diplomatic pressure from China.

Comment: @EarlGrey As per the link you gave: they did not kill for fun, they accidently killed while flying irresponsibly. They were discharged from the service May 1999, not 15 years later. They were charged with manslaughter and found non guilty; the state may not mandate punishment like that with a trial, of course. One of the airman spend four months in jail for destroying the tape.

Comment: @prosfilaes thanks for the useful and interesting insights.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming the laws of war, the embassy may have been a valid **military target**. Protocol I to the Geneva Conventions, Article 52, states that a legitimate military target is a target

> which by their nature, location, purpose or **use** make an effective contribution to military action and whose total or partial destruction, capture or neutralization, in the circumstances ruling at the time, offers a definite military advantage ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legitimate_military_target)).

The embassy contained the fragments of the top secret F-117 stealth aircraft that can be **used** for reverse-engineering. This would have made an effective contribution because China lacked the stealth technology at that time. Hence be the countries at war, this is a valid military target, does not matter whom belongs.

The laws of war are valid during the war. It may be a question if these fragments of F-117 are worth starting the war against China (likely expecting to end it right after the strike but still very risky). China would be free to hit any USA military target while the war is ongoing or opt to continue the war the way it sees fit. But USA may be a tough enough enemy even for China so both sides would likely be more interested in de-escalating. No war was declared but the declaration of war is not a requirement for the state of war to exist ([source](https://casebook.icrc.org/glossary/declaration-war)).

If may fully be that the war have never been seen as a good idea and the embassy has been hit indeed by chance.

Comment: Hitting military targets of another country means obviously the war. This aircraft wreck may not be worth it.

Comment: Except the US was not legally at war with China.

Comment: A declaration of war is not necessary for the state of war to exist. Bombing the embassy deliberately would put the state of war automatically.

Comment: So you're saying the US was trying to "Pearl Harbour" China like that?